# My question is, How to ignore a element after traversing it one time in c

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, counting

[As I am a beginner, I m not getting the answer of this that, in this case, 2 is counted that it's 4 times, but it is also counting the repeating elements of 2 in array again.]

**//Write a program in C to find the number occurring an odd number of times in an array** [please check the image of what I am asking drawn in paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1ESq.png)

To find all the elements occurring odd times.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

int main() {
    int arr[MAX], n, i;
    printf("Enter size of array : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter element in array : ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("index - [%d] : ", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    int count;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count % 2 != 0) {
            printf(" %d ", arr[i]);
        }
    }
    if (count % 2 == 0)
        printf("No elements appeared odd times in array .");
    else
        printf(" appeared odd times in array . ");
}
```

Comment: Just calculate the XOR (sum) of all values. Note: this question is a duplicate, this is why I just put this answer as a comment (never easy to find the duplicate precisely...). Demo: `a xor a xor a = a`

Comment: @Damien This will not work at least when it is 0 that is encountered odd times.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why will not work? If we get 0 as result, then 0 is the only number met an odd number of times

Comment: @Damien Two zeroes and three zeroes will give the same result of the operation xor.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Before edition, the post said *All numbers occur an even number of times except one number which occurs an odd number of times*. With this indication, my proposal works, whatever the number to find is 0 or not. Of course, if you can have several numbers that occur an odd number of times, this is a different story. I just notice the edition of the post. Ambiguous now.

Comment: @Damien I agree with you.

Comment: Yeah! Now I understand the logic , it will be only 1 time and I was trying to print all the odd occurances.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do this but,

I would sort the array first. Find the different types of algorithms here: https://www.educba.com/sorting-in-c/

Then write code to go through each group of numbers and determine if there is an even number of x or not and move on to the next group of x.

Answer (score 0):

You do not break the loops when an element with an odd times of repetitions is found.

If you are not allowed to change the array when the loops can look the following way

```
int count = 0;

for ( i = 0; i < n && count % 2 == 0; i += count == 0 )
{
    count = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while ( j < i && a[j] != a[i] ) j++;

    if ( j == i )
    {
        count ^= 1;
        while ( ++j < n )
        {
            if ( a[j] == a[i] ) count ^= 1;
        }
    }    
}

if ( count )
{
    printf( "%d appeared odd times in array.\n", a[i] );
}
else
{  
    puts( "No elements appeared odd times in array." );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program written based on your code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2 };
    int n = ( int )( sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );
    int i;  
    int count = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < n && count % 2 == 0; i += count == 0 )
    {
        count = 0;
        int j = 0;

        while ( j < i && a[j] != a[i] ) j++;

        if ( j == i )
        {
            count ^= 1;
            while ( ++j < n )
            {
                if ( a[j] == a[i] ) count ^= 1;
            }
        }    
    }

    if ( count )
    {
        printf( "%d appeared odd times in array.\n", a[i] );
    }
    else
    {  
        puts( "No elements appeared odd times in array." );
    } 
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 appeared odd times in array.
```

Comment: @chqrlie In this case we will need to decrease i one more.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only a single number that appears odd times in the array, it is possible to solve it with O(n) time complexity with only one traversal using XOR, as was said above.

Assuming the range of integers is limited, e.g. you know that all numbers are in the range [-k , k], then it can be solved in O(n+k) using a LUT (Lookup Table). If n is always bigger than k, then you can say it is "O(n)".

Otherwise, I don't think there is a way to solve this problem in O(n).
In the worst case, all numbers appear once (which is an odd number of times) in the array, which means that in every iteration while traversing the array, you will need to store the value that was encountered and check if it already appeared before, and these actions will take at least O(log(n)) without a Lookup Table.
So, the full algorithm will have O(n log(n)) time complexity at best, in which case it is easier to just sort the array, as Cam Klein said. Even if you're allowed to go through the original array only once, you can copy it to another array or data structure and sort it.

The solution with a Lookup Table, assuming all values in the array are in the range [0, 100], will go like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100
#define MIN_RANGE 0
#define MAX_RANGE 100

int main() {
    int arr[MAX], n, i;
    static int lut[MAX_RANGE - MIN_RANGE + 1]
    printf("Enter size of array : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter element in array : ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("index - [%d] : ", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    int count = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        lut[arr[i] - MIN_RANGE] += 1;
    }
    
    for (i = MIN_RANGE; i <= MAX_RANGE; i++) {
        if (lut[i] % 2 == 1) {
             ++count;
             printf("%d appeared odd times in array.\n", i);
        }
    }
    if (count == 0)
    {  
        puts("No elements appeared odd times in array.");
    } 
}
```